# Show that $f<\infty$ almost anywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, riemann-integration

I have recently been introduced with integrals for measurable functions. I have the following definitions:

**Definition 1:** For a measurable functions $f:S\to[0,\infty]$ and a sequence of simple functions $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ with $0\leq f_n\uparrow f$ we define the integral of $f$ over $E\in\mathcal{A}$ as $$\int_E fd\mu = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_E f_n d\mu, \text{ in } [0,\infty],$$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of $S$.

**Definition 2:** A measurable function $f:S\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is called integrable when both $\int_S f^{+}d\mu$ and $\int_S f^{-}d\mu$ are finite. In this case the integral of $f$ over $E\in\mathcal{A}$ is defined as $$\int_E fd\mu = \int_E f^{+}d\mu - \int_E f^{-}d\mu.$$

I have to solve the following exercise:

**Exercise:** Let $f:S\to[0,\infty]$ be a integrable function. Show that $f<\infty$ almost everywhere.

*What I think I should do:* I think that I need to show that $\int_S f^{+}d\mu$ and $\int_S f^{-}d\mu$ finite implies that $f<\infty$ almost everywhere.

**Questions:**

- How do I show that $\int_S f^{+}d\mu$ and $\int_S f^{-}d\mu$ finite implies that $f<\infty$ almost everywhere? I'm particularly confused by the part *almost everywhere*. If $f \nless \infty$ *somewhere*, wouldn't this imply that $\int_S f^{+}d\mu$ is infinite?
- How do integrals for measurable functions differ from the Riemann integral? I've learned about the Riemann integral before and I don't really understand what the difference is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's important to know $0\cdot\infty=0$, in measure theory at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:S\to[0,\infty]$ is integrable, then $f \ge 0$ , thus $f=f^{+}$ and $f^{-}=0$.

Let $A:=\{x \in S: f(x)= + \infty\}$. For each natural $n$ we have $n \cdot 1_ A \le f$, hence

$n \mu(A)=\int_S n \cdot 1_ A d \mu \le \int_s f d \mu < \infty$ for all $n$. This gives $\mu(A)=0$.

Your second question: consider $f=1_{\mathbb Q}$. $f$ is Lebesgue integrable over $[0,1]$, but not Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How do you know that $n\mu(A) = \int_S 1_A d\mu$? What if there are infinitely many $x\in A$?

Comment: Sorry, a typo ! It should read: $n \mu(A)=\int_S n \cdot 1_ A d \mu $.

Answer (score 0):

I only answer the first question of yours. The second question is asked here several times and you can find many interesting answers.

Okay, let's start. "Almost everywhere" means that a property holds everywhere except for a null set. What is a null set? A null set is a measurable set  such that it's measure is zero. So you can for example say the following function is $1$ almost everywhere (using the Lebesgue measure) , where the function is $1$ in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and something else in $\mathbb{Q}$. Because $\mathbb{Q}$ has Lebesgue measure zero (why?).

For the excercise you have a function $f$ that is non-negative, so $f^+=f$. To prove the statement $f<\infty$ almost everywhere, we do it by contradiction. Assume there is some non null set $K$ for which $f(x)=\infty$ for all $x\in K$.  Then we have:
\begin{align}
\infty= \int_K fd\mu= \int_K f^+d\mu\leq \int_S f^+d\mu<\infty
\end{align} 
A contradiction. Hence the claim follows.